# Calling mkdir to home directory creates said directory in current working directory?

Tags: linux, bash

I am inside a bash script located at `/home/[username]/Documents/work/script.sh`. I want to create two folders, `potato/tomato` at `/home/[username]/`. To do so, here's my script:

`mkdir -p "~/potato/tomato"`

However, this creates the two folders like this: `/home/[username]/Documents/work/potato/tomato`.

I don't want to create these folders in my current working directory, I want them in my current user's home directory. What am I doing wrong and what should I change?

Comment: try without "", 

mkdir -p ~/potato/tomato

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes:

```
mkdir -p ~/potato/tomato
```

By using quotes, it's evaluating the home directory and using your username as a name in the path, starting from the current working directly. Without the quotes, it will evaluate correctly to the absolutely path of your home directory.

Comment: Is that a feature or a bug in the shell? ;-)